# Children dynamic content with reactjs

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to experiment here. I want to build a component that auto populates some data from an ajax request after mounting. Something like this:

```
var AjaxComponent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: {}
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.data.text}
            </div>
        );
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        makeAjaxResquest(this.props.url).then(function(response){
            this.setState({
                data: response.body // or something
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }

});
```

With that example component, I'd use `<AjaxComponent url="/url/to/fetch" />` to display the content.

Now, what if I'd like to access different bits of data from children elements? Can I do something like this?

```
<AjaxComponent url="/url/to/fetch">
    <div>
        <header>{RESPONSE.title}</header>
        <div>
            {RESPONSE.text}
        </div>
    </div>
</AjaxComponent>
```

No problem if it doesn't render anything before the ajax request ends. The thing is how could I pass the data for children to render, *not as props*. Is it possible?

Comment: Why *not as props*? It seems like the most logical approach.

Comment: Passing data as props wouldn't make it available from a parent component that renders AjaxComponent as a child. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar scenario where I had similar Components that would query data from different APIs. Assuming you know the expected response from a given API, you could do it the same way perhaps.

Essentially make a generic Component where it props functions as an "API" of sorts, then define different types of sub components and their associated render function.

For example:

In widget, you then do something like this, where widgets is just a plain javascript file with a bunch of functions:

```
componentDidMount: widgets[type].componentDidMount(),

render: widgets[type].render().
```

In widgets, it would be like this:

```
var widgets = {
 widget1: {
    componentDidMount: function () {
              //Ajax call..
     },

     render: function() {
     //How should I draw?

     }

},

 widget2: //Same format, different functions
```

Then in some parent component you simply go 
   < Widget type="widget1" \>

or whatever.

There are a couple weird things about this that probably don't sit right with React. First off, you should take state all the way up to the top-level component, so I wouldn't do my ajax calls in componentDidMount...I'd more likely get the data I want for the widgets I want to render at a higher level, then pass that in as a prop too if it won't change until I make another API call (thinking Flux style flow here). Then, just pass in the data as a prop as well and just specify the render functions:

```
< Widget data={this.state.data[0]} type=widget1 />
```

The "gotcha" here is that you are making an assumption that whatever is in this data prop will match what you need in the widget type. I would pass in an object, and then validate it all in the render function etc.

That's one way. Not sure if it's valid, I'm sure someone who knows more could pick it apart but it suited my use case and I now have a library of similar components that I can selectively render by passing in data and a type, then looking up the appropriate render function and checking to make sure the data object contains everything I need to render.